# Is there any way to catch AWS lambda timed out error in code level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there any way to catch `AWS lambda timed out` error in code-level so that I can have a chance to handle for the error before exiting the `lambda` function?

Comment: Might be of help: `context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()` (and node/others equivalents) will give you the remaining execution time

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While the lambda environment doesn't fire a "timing out" event, you can do this yourself fairly trivially.

Each language has a function exposed by the `context` object
to [get the remaining time in milliseconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html).

You can use that, in tandem with the timer functionality of whatever language you're using to ensure you get notified before timeout.

For example (node):

```
function handler(event, context, callback) {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("oh no i'm going to timeout in 3 seconds!");
    // &c.
  }, context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() - 3 * 1000);
  try {
    // rest of code...
  } finally {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  callback(null, result);
}
```

Comment: Ensure? I don't see how can this reliably "catch" a timeout, what if you're using a blocking third party library that takes 5 seconds to do a certain task?

Comment: Yes- this is definitely an edge case. If you're doing something incredibly long and synchronous then you'll never be able to detect timeout. However, in my experience at least, these are not very common in node. For example, all of node's standard library is async (yields control), as does all of the aws-sdk. In the case of a slow function that doesn't yield to the event loop, I don't think you'll ever be able to detect a timeout, short of editing the function to periodically check.

Comment: Yup I think you're right about node, in my case everything is done in python unfortunately, I guess having a task checking every 15 minutes for other tasks that haven't closed their process flow and then retry or break into smaller tasks is a solution

Comment: @Mojimi You could modify the above, to instead throw an exception say X seconds before the end. So you catch your own exception and handle, rather than trying to catch some exception at the Lambda level. At least it would allow you to gracefully handle your long-running process.

Comment: For the Python users, here are examples of the `context` object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html  Thanks to @thomasmichaelwallace for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Be sure to wrap `// rest of code...` in a try-finally, and place the `clearTimeout` in the `finally` block. Without this, if your lambda has an unhandled exception, the timeout isn't cleared, and a future lambda invocation may end up handling the timeout callback for the previous (failed) lambda invocation (since lambda reuses nodejs runtime if there's a demand for it).

Comment: @VMaharajh is there documentation explaining/warning about this?  Have you witnessed or anecdotally heard about this happening?  Links appreciated.

Comment: @danronmoon I witnessed it when implementing this. You should be able to simulate this to verify that the behavior occurs in your runtime. I was on node js 12 when I tested this.

Answer (score 23):

###### Update:

Use the built-in `Promise.race()` function instead:

```js
module.exports.myFunction = async (event) => {

  // your real task
  const task = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ statusCode: 200, message: 'Task finished.' }), 1000);
  })

  // add a new "task": timeout 
  const timeout = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ statusCode: 504, message: 'Sorry, your task timed out!' }), 200);
  })
  
  // start them synchronously
  const res = await Promise.race([task, timeout]);
  return res;
};
```

---

###### Original Answer:

I would like to share my solution here:
Let's say I have a Lambda handler function and its timeout limit I set was 15 mins.
Inside this function, I have an async function named `work()` which may takes longer that 15 mins.

To catch the timeout error from Lambda, my way is: 
I create a new async function named `timeout()`, and this function simply return after 14.9 mins.
And I let `work()` and `timeout()` functions start at the same time, if `work()` can finish in 14.9 mins, then `work()` returns earlier that `timeout()`, otherwise, `timeout()` returns earlier.
You can see it easier with this diagram:

[image]

And this is just what `race()` operator does from `rxjs`.

Here is the code that implement this idea by using `rxjs`:

```
module.exports.myFunction = async (event) => {
  function task() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('finished!');
      }, 15 * 60 * 1000);
    });
  }

  function timeout() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('timeout!');
      }, 14.9 * 60 * 1000);
    });
  }


  const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    race(from(task()), from(timeout()))
      .subscribe(msg => {
        resolve(msg);
      })
  });

  return { res };
};
```