# Alexa skill is giving 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response', can we change this message to custom message?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, session-timeout

I am new to Alexa skill, and I am developing an Alexa skill, in my case there are scenario when I don't want to wait for http response to back and if my lambda timeouts due to delay in response from Http can I give a custom message in place of 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response'. My code is :

```
  'ProtectArmIntent': function() {
    if(checkAccessToken(this.event.session.user.accessToken)){
      var data = {
        mode: HUB_MODE.ARM,
        regId: "null"
      }
      callAPI("post", API_COMMANDS.HUB_MODE, data, this.event.session.user.accessToken)
          .then((body) => {
            if(body.response.status === "SUCCESS"){
              this.emit(':tell', messages.ARM.SUCCESSFUL);
            } else {
              this.emit(':tell', messages.ARM.FAILED);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              this.emit('SessionEndedRequest');
            //errorHandler.call(this, err, messages.ARM.FAILED);
          });
    } else {
      this.emit('LinkAccount');
    }
  },
```

and alexa simulator request:

"request": {
    "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.67e1612e-f8a4-43f5-ab28-175ba7d7941f",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-13T21:13:11Z",
    "locale": "en-GB",
    "reason": "ERROR",
    "error": {
        "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
        "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
    }
}

I know the issue is because lambda timeout as delay in the HTTP response, so can I give some customize message like Your command is accepted and it will be executed in some time.

Please please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Making your own timer function might help. Set your timer lower than the lambda timeout and send your response at the end of the timer which will of course not lead to a lambda timeout error.[This answer might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478273/11440698)